# mount.nfs: Connection timed out on ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, nfs, ubuntu-server, nfsclient

I trying to create a nfs server for the first time. On trying to mount to the server I am getting an error "mount.nfs: Connection timed out". My server version is ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS while my client is ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Following are the step that I have performed.

On Server Side:

**# vi /etc/exports**

```
/home/nfs           192.168.13.81(rw,async,no_root_squash)
```

**# sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart**

**# sudo exportfs -u**

```
/home/nfs       192.168.13.81
```

On Client Side:

**# sudo mount 192.168.13.80:/home/nfs /home/nfs**

```
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

on trying,

**#sudo mount -t nfs4 -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.13.80:/home/nfs /home/nfs**

```
mount.nfs4: mounting 192.168.13.80:/home/nfs failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

"# rpcinfo -p" gives:

```
program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  39340  status
    100024    1   tcp  49970  status
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
```

I am not sure what or how else to try. Please help. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Not required restart `nfs` service. After you add below in `/etc/exports`

```
/home/nfs           192.168.13.81(rw,async,no_root_squash)
```

Just re-export the NFS directories:

```
exportfs -ra
```

Then use `nfs4` to mount it.

```
mount -t nfs4 192.168.13.80:/home/nfs /home/nfs
```

You may also want to check if client has NFS access to server by the following command.

```
rpcinfo -p 192.168.13.80
```

You will get result if client has access, with lines as *portmapper*, *nfs*, *mountd*, *nlockmgr*, *nfs_acl* and *rquotad*.